# How to depoy code in magento2 cloud project?

Tags: magento2, code, deployment, magento2-cloud, adobe-commerce

I have following queries as a beginner for the **Magento/Adobe Commerce Cloud** project.

1. How we can do the deployment process?
2. What is the best practice to do the deployment process?
3. Can we create new feature branch or We need to use the
   default(integration,staging,production,master) branches for
   deployment process based on our selected plan?

Please share your views so it will help every beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Here are answers to your queries:

**1. How can we do the deployment process?**

The deployment process for Magento/Adobe Commerce Cloud typically involves the following steps:

Code Management: Ensure that your Magento codebase is managed using version control systems (VCS) like Git. Adobe Commerce Cloud provides integration with GitHub or Bitbucket repositories.

Branch Management: Typically, you'll have branches like develop, integration, staging, and master for different stages of the development life-cycle.

Code Deployment: Use deployment tools or services to push changes from your development environment to testing, staging, and production environments. Adobe Commerce Cloud provides deployment pipelines for seamless integration and deployment.

Testing: Perform thorough testing of changes in the testing and staging environments before promoting them to production. This includes functional testing, performance testing, security testing, and user acceptance testing (UAT).

**2. What is the best practice to do the deployment process?**
Here are some best practices for the deployment process in Magento/Adobe Commerce Cloud:

Automated Deployment: Automate the deployment process using CI/CD (Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment) pipelines. This ensures consistency, reduces manual errors, and speeds up the deployment process.

Environment Parity: Ensure that development, testing, staging, and production environments are as similar as possible. This includes server configurations, Magento configurations, and third-party integrations.

Version Control: Use Git for version control and follow Git best practices such as feature branching, pull requests, and code reviews.

Dependency Management: Use Composer for managing dependencies and ensure that third-party modules and libraries are properly versioned and documented.

Monitoring and Logging: Implement monitoring and logging solutions to track application performance, errors, and security issues across environments.

**3. Can we create a new feature branch or use the default branches?**
It's a common practice to create feature branches for developing new features or implementing changes. Feature branches allow developers to work on isolated changes without affecting the main development branch (develop or integration). Once the feature is completed and tested, it can be merged into the main development branch.

The default branches (integration, staging, master) are typically used for deployment to different environments. Changes are promoted from one environment to another through these branches using deployment pipelines.

In summary, you can create new feature branches for development and use the default branches for deployment based on your selected deployment plan and branching strategy.

Comment: I am looking for full steps.... Like whether we can create feature branch or not because my cloud project not allowing me to create new branch.